# PyYAML shows "ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here" in my unittest

Tags: python-2.7, pyyaml

I am trying to test a number of Python 2.7 classes using unittest.

Here is the exception:

```
ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here
    in "<unicode string>", line 3, column 32:
            ... file1_with_path: '../../testdata/concat1.csv'
```

Here is the example the error message relates to:

```
class TestConcatTransform(unittest.TestCase):

def setUp(self):
    filename1 = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + '/../../testdata/concat1.pkl'
    self.df1 = pd.read_pickle(filename1)
    filename2 = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + '/../../testdata/concat2.pkl'
    self.df2 = pd.read_pickle(filename2)

    self.yamlconfig =  u'''
        --- !ConcatTransform
        file1_with_path: '../../testdata/concat1.csv'
        file2_with_path: '../../testdata/concat2.csv'
        skip_header_lines: [0]
        duplicates: ['%allcolumns']
        outtype: 'dataframe'
        client: 'testdata'
        addcolumn: []
    '''
    self.testconcat = yaml.load(self.yamlconfig)
```

What is the the problem?

Something not clear to me is that the directory structure I have is:

```
app
app/etl
app/tests
```

The `ConcatTransform` is in `app/etl/concattransform.py` and `TestConcatTransform` is in `app/tests`. I import `ConcatTransform` into the `TestConcatTransform` unittest with this import:

```
from app.etl import concattransform
```

How does PyYAML associate that class with the one defined in yamlconfig?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A YAML document can start with a document start marker `---`, but that has to be at the beginning of a line, and yours is indented eight positions on the second line of the input. That causes the `---` to be interpreted as the beginning of a  multi-line plain (i.e. non-quoted) scalar, and within such a scalar you cannot have a `:` (colon + space). You can only have `:` in quoted scalars. And if your document does not have a mapping or sequence at the root level, as yours doesn't,  the whole document can only consists of a single scalar.

If you want to keep your sources nicely indented like you have now, I recommend you use `dedent` from `textwrap`.

The following runs without error:

```
import ruamel.yaml
from textwrap import dedent

yaml_config = dedent(u'''\
        --- !ConcatTransform
        file1_with_path: '../../testdata/concat1.csv'
        file2_with_path: '../../testdata/concat2.csv'
        skip_header_lines: [0]
        duplicates: ['%allcolumns']
        outtype: 'dataframe'
        client: 'testdata'
        addcolumn: []
''')

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(yaml_config)
```

You should get into the habit to put the backslash (`\`) at the end of your first triple-quotes, so your YAML document. If you do that, your error would have actually indicated line 2 because the document doesn't start with an empty line anymore.

---

During loading the YAML parser encouncters the tag `!ConcatTransform`. A constructor for an object is probably registered with the PyYAML loader, associating that tag with the  using PyYAML's `add_constructor`, during the import.

Unfortunately they registered their constructor with the default, non-safe, loader, which is not necessary, they could have registered with the `SafeLoader`, and thereby not force users to risk problems with non-controlled input.

Comment: I am using `ruamel.yaml` in the above to test the YAML, as it can handle non-registred tags when using the default round-trip-mode (which is safe). Without constructor  [PyYAML barfs](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/?yaml=---+!ConcatTransform%0Afile1_with_path%3A+%27..%2F..%2Ftestdata%2Fconcat1.csv%27%0Afile2_with_path%3A+%27..%2F..%2Ftestdata%2Fconcat2.csv%27%0Askip_header_lines%3A+%5B0%5D%0Aduplicates%3A+%5B%27%25allcolumns%27%5D%0Aouttype%3A+%27dataframe%27%0Aclient%3A+%27testdata%27%0Aaddcolumn%3A+%5B%5D%0A&type=json) even when dedented.